# How to use Jbutton in if statements in java

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to use The Jbutton action listener clicks for to set my pressed variable from 0 to 1,2, or 3. if this number becomes switched then will the suites of cards on the text field. My problem is not setting my pressed variable equal to a new number and just keeping it at 0.

My main file

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cardapp;

/**
 *
 * @author Angela
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CardApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton oneButton, 
                    twoButton, 
                    threeButton;  
    private int width = 25;
    private int height = 15;
    private JTextField TextField = new JTextField(3); 
    Hand handObject = new Hand();
    private int pressedNumber;


    public CardApp() {

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));        



        oneButton = new JButton("1");
        twoButton = new JButton("2");
        threeButton = new JButton("3");


        // Listen for events on each button
        oneButton.addActionListener(this);
        twoButton.addActionListener(this);
        threeButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Add each to the panel of buttons
        buttonPanel.add(oneButton); 
        buttonPanel.add(twoButton); 
        buttonPanel.add(threeButton); 
       // Add everything to a main panel attached to the content pane
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(TextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setTitle("Sabacc Example by Angela Rucci");
        setSize(375, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        handObject.Discards(pressedNumber);
        TextField.setText(handObject.ListOfCards());

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (e.getSource() == oneButton){
                        pressedNumber = 1;
                        handObject.Discards(pressedNumber);
                        }
                if (e.getSource() == twoButton){
                        pressedNumber = 2;
                        handObject.Discards(pressedNumber);
                        }
                if (e.getSource() == threeButton){
                        pressedNumber = 3;
                        handObject.Discards(pressedNumber);
                        }

                TextField.setText(handObject.ListOfCards());



    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardApp c = new CardApp();
}

}
```

my file where it will generate a new suit for the pressed button.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cardapp;
import java.util.Random;
//import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import javax.swing.*;
//import java.awt.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Angela
 */

public class Hand {
String [] Suits = {"C", "H", "S", "D"};
String [] probability = {"C","H","R","S","D"};
Random randomInt = new Random ();
String RandomSuit;
String RandomShuffle;
String ThreeSuits; 
String LeftSuit;
String MiddleSuit;
String RightSuit;
int pressed;


       public int Discards(int pressedNumber){
                            Randomizer();
              return pressed;

             }



       public void Randomizer (){

           int RandomSuitNumber = randomInt.nextInt(4);//this is generator a random number

           //------------------Decide what hand to randomize --------------------------//
           if (pressed==1){
                  LeftSuit= Suits[RandomSuitNumber];

                  }

              if (pressed==2){
                 MiddleSuit=Suits[RandomSuitNumber];

                 }

              if (pressed==3){
                  RightSuit=Suits[RandomSuitNumber];}

          //----------------20% chance of new random set------------------------------------//
            int ProabilityRandomNum = randomInt.nextInt(5);
            RandomShuffle= probability[ProabilityRandomNum];


          //------------If proability array equals R then change all of the suits----------//  
            if (RandomShuffle.equals("R") || pressed== 0){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Randomized Hand!");

                int leftNumber = randomInt.nextInt(4);
                int middleNumber = randomInt.nextInt(4);
                int rightNumber = randomInt.nextInt(4);

                LeftSuit= Suits[leftNumber];
                MiddleSuit= Suits[middleNumber];
                RightSuit= Suits[rightNumber];}

            ThreeSuits = (LeftSuit + MiddleSuit + RightSuit); 
       }


       public String ListOfCards (){
               return ThreeSuits;
             }



       public void GameOver(){
              if (LeftSuit == MiddleSuit && MiddleSuit == RightSuit && RightSuit== LeftSuit){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WINNER!!");
                 }
             }
}
```

Comment: Now, admittedly, I've had very little sleep, so I'm easily confused, but I honestly have no idea what your problem is.  Are you asking if the value of  `pressedNumber` is greater then the value of the button been clicked it shouldn't change?  You talk about keeping it `0`, but why would you change the value at all if you just wanted to keep it at `0`?

Comment: No i do not want to keep it zero, i want the value to change when one of the buttons is clicked.

Comment: You pass `pressedNumber ` to `Hand#Discards`, but never actually use it?

Comment: You never set Hand.pressed;  do you want to put an assignment in the Discards method?

Comment: yes but i am trying to use it though

Comment: Yes i want to assign the pressed button to press so i can change the character of the the button. I am trying to create a card game were you start out have Three different Suits. Depending on the button you press(1 2 or 3) it will change the suit. the goal is to get three of the same suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the value of `pressedNumber` from `CardApp` to `Hand`, but never actually use it...

```
public int Discards(int pressedNumber) {
    Randomizer();
    return pressed;
}
```

Did you mean to do something like...

```
public int Discards(int pressedNumber) {
    pressed = pressedNumber;
    Randomizer();
    return pressed;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to my club :P

Comment: @AngelaRucci: It's a very large club.